# Cabal Configure Failed Ubuntu + IntelliJ plugin

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

So I am trying out a Haskell developing with the following IntelliJ plugin:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7453?pr=

GitHub page here:

https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell

The only issue I have with this plugin is as follows: When I try to run my code I keep getting this error message saying that the Cabal Configure Failed. NOTE: Before anyone asks, I have told IntelliJ that GHCs is located at usr/bin/ghc. And yes, I am running Ubuntu-MATE 16.04

Why am I getting this error, and is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: Cabal --version returns the following output:

```
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

Running Cabal Configure, from terminal, in my project directory results in the following output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Test-0.0.1...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
doctest -any
```

And IntelliJ knows my cabal data path to be:

```
/home/avi/.cabal
```

Comment: Do you have `cabal` installed? Does IntelliJ know where it is? Does your project have a `.cabal` file? Can you run `cabal configure` from the command line? Can you show us the output of `cabal configure` (run it when in your project directory)

Comment: @ErikR See the edit I made o my question